# How to search linked question with specific tag?

Tags: support, tags, search

For example, I want to search php tag questions linked with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/linked/588004?lq=1, how can I filter them?

Comment: What do you mean by "filter"? Filter for what? Filter which way?

Comment: This was a feature once (backlinks being a regular search attribute). It was dropped unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately you can't with the on-site search.

However, you can just use a SEDE [query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/881111?postid=588004&tagname=php).

```sql
select concat('site://q/', q.id, '|', q.title) as [Linked post]
from postlinks pl
inner join posts q on q.id = pl.postid
inner join posttags pt on pt.postid = q.id
inner join tags t on t.id = pt.tagid
where relatedpostid = ##postid:int?588004##
and t.tagname = ##tagname:string?php##
and linktypeid = 1 -- linked (not duplicate, use 3 for that)
```

This query uses the PostLinks table that represent the linked questions page you referred  to. From there we can join on the Posts table (for the title) as well as on posttags and tags to filter on a specific tag.

See [Database schema documentation for the public data dump and SEDE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede) for more background on what these tables and their values mean.

Keep in mind SEDE is only updated once a week, on Sunday around 03:00 UTC. If you're new to SEDE or SQL, give the [tutorial](https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial) a try and/or share feedback in [chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/rooms/1223/data-explorer-sede).